# Why is the XSLT disable-output-escaping not implemented in Firefox?

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt

This is an issue that recently came up for me while writing a new XSLT for some XML generated by an application with XTHML embedded using CDATA. Normally I've been able to use [disable-output-escaping](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping) to render the results correctly.

However, in Firefox, everything was being displayed as escaped (i.e. &amp;) as opposed to rendering as expected, since Firefox tends to be my primary browser when developing this resulted me losing some time trying to figure out what I was doing wrong before finding [Firefox Bug 98168](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98168) describing the issue.

Right now it looks like this issue is not slated to be implemented in Firefox and I've been reading through the bug's comments and it looks like the decision was made back in 2001. As such, I was hoping someone might be able to explain what the issue is and if it still applies now in 2009? Also, if this is never going to be fixed in Firefox, is there a workaround for it besides using another browser?

Comment: This question is tagged "standards-compliance," but there is no issue of compliance here. As the spec you linked to says, "...An XSLT processor is **not required** to support disabling output escaping. If an xsl:value-of or xsl:text specifies that output escaping should be disabled and the XSLT processor does not support this, the XSLT processor may signal an error; *if it does not signal an error, it **must recover by not disabling output escaping***." Firefox does exactly the latter, right? I wish Firefox supported more of XSLT, but in this respect it complies with the standard.

Comment: I'm not sure what constitutes "resurrecting." I made my comment because the value in questions and answers is often long past the date they were asked. Lack of d-o-e in Firefox is an issue still today (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/29487039/423105 which linked to this question), and one that often surprises XSLT developers because it's not very obvious. The value of Qs & As is greater when they're tagged correctly. But it's possible that someone could be looking for info about this topic thinking it's a compliance issue.

Comment: I would rather give the OP a chance to approve tag changes if there's any room for disagreement, but since you don't object, I'll go ahead and change the tagging. The necessity for the comment was to give you a chance to make the case for your tagging choice if you so desired. I do that because I would appreciate being treated that way. If you don't care, that's fine too.

Comment: @LarsH Stack Overflow is a community wiki so we don't "own" the questions, I think after a couple weeks have gone by you can safely just change things as needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98168#c99 and subsequent comments describe the current status of the bug: "disable-output-escaping" can be implemented in Firefox, but it requires a different approach when processing the stylesheet than the one used by Firefox's XSLT processor (serialize+parse instead of creating a DOM tree while processing the stylesheet). Patches are accepted, but it seems that no-one plans to spend time on fixing the issue.

Even if it's implemented, such stylesheets will require more CPU resources to be processed, and Mozilla developers say that usually there's a better solution than using d-o-e. If you want help in your specific case, you should describe it in more detail (although I probably won't be able to help).