# Special characters in XSL

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm working on a XSL 1.0 transformation to get HTML visualisation when displaying the XML in Firefox.
In my original XML, I have characters like

```
&amp;eacute; &amp;egrave; &amp;lsquo;...
```

I need to convert them into

```
é, è, ‘...
```

I have used this template :

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
  <xsl:param name="text" />
  <xsl:param name="replace" />
  <xsl:param name="by" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
      <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Calling for each special character (here for example &egrave;) :

```
            <xsl:variable name="newtext">
              <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$originaltext" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&amp;egrave;'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'è'" />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
```

Is there a solution where I can directly replace `&amp;` into & for example without the need to call the replacement template for each special character I expect to exist?

Comment: The only improvement I can think of off-hand, without switching to XSLT 2.0, would be to create a "table" of special characters in your stylesheet and loop through it recursively, calling `string-replace-all` for each "row" in the table on the output the previous call. However there may be a better option involving extension functions, e.g, http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html depending on what XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: I need to use Firefox to display directly the XML with its transformation without special preprocessor.

Comment: OK, since Firefox is your environment, why not have your stylesheet output some Javascript. The JS code can, after the page is loaded, go through and perform a replacement of `&amp;` with `&`. I'm not sure it would work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work with the resulting XML from XSL Transfo. I had finally to create an XSL stylesheet with all HTML characters double encoded and their result.. Painful and ugly but it works. Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me in (an old version of) Firefox:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mystyle.xsl"?>
<root>
    <description>Article Containing Escaped Entitites</description>
    <content>Lor&amp;eacute;m ipsum &amp;lsquo;dolor&amp;lsquo; sit am&amp;egrave;t, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</content>
</root>
```

**mystyle.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2><xsl:value-of select="description"/></h2>
            <p id="content">
                <xsl:value-of select="content"/>
            </p>

            <script>
    var element = document.getElementById("content");
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/&amp;amp;/g,'&amp;');
            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result (screenshot):**

[image]

***Caveat***: I am not a Javascript expert; this is just something I cobbled together on impulse.

Comment: This is a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a solution where I can directly replace & into & for
>   example without the need to call the replacement template for each
>   special character I expect to exist?

Why don't you simply disable the escaping when outputting the text? For example, given an input of:

```
<content>Lor&amp;eacute;m ipsum &amp;lsquo;dolor&amp;lsquo; sit am&amp;egrave;t, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</content>
```

you can have your stylesheet process this as:

```
<p>
    <xsl:value-of select="content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</p>
```

and return:

```
<p>Lor&eacute;m ipsum &lsquo;dolor&lsquo; sit am&egrave;t, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
```

which a browser should render as:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, the problem is that that I have double encoding, for example "à" is encoded "&amp;agrave;" in my XML. When I use disable-output-escaping the final result in the browser is "&agrave;"

Comment: @SouhaibGuitouni Why is that a problem? That's exactly how it needs to be: escaped ("&amp;agrave;") in XML, unescaped ("&agrave;") in HTML.

Comment: I've been looking for the reason of the problem, the browser (Firefox in my case) does not handle disable-output-escaping. It simply ignores it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137241/why-is-the-xslt-disable-output-escaping-not-implemented-in-firefox
As a result, &amp;agrave; is shown always &agrave;

Comment: d-o-e was a good idea, but as the XSLT spec says, the XSLT processor is not obligated to honor a d-o-e request (because it sometimes has no control over serialization).

Comment: @SouhaibGuitouni I believe your options are limited to: (1) do the transformation server-side; (2) use another browser; or (3) post-process the resulting HTML using Javascript - see an example in my other answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
String htmlstring = "Put Your HTML string here"
            + htmlstringbuf
                    .toString()
                    .replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ")
                    .replaceAll("&", "&amp;")
                    .replaceAll("null", " ")
                    .replaceAll("<\\?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"\\?>"," ")
                    .replaceAll("Â", "<br></br>")
                    .replaceAll("<\\?xml version = '1.0' encoding ='UTF-8'\\?>",
                            " ") + "</body>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me where insert this script? I have trouble testing it out

Comment: this is code to create html string and replace all special character from string put this to where your are making html string .... may this will work and help you...

Comment: Is this intended to be javascript? java? How would you suggest integrating it into an XSLT stylesheet? Also, most of the given calls to `replaceAll()` are not doing what the OP requested.

Comment: first you have to make html using combination of XSLT and XML.... write??? and then you will get html that time you have to use above code in java....